# DOM4J xpath-select colon node with namespace

Tags: java, namespaces, dom4j

Given the xml content is as below;

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><CreateResponse xmlns="http://gtestserver/"><CustomerId>8124138</CustomerId><InternalResponseCode>Success</InternalResponseCode><ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode><ResponseDate>2016-08-31T07:57:22.7760577Z</ResponseDate><ResponseDescription>Success</ResponseDescription><UserId>7424876375</UserId></CreateResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I need to pickup the node :**CustomerId** ,but i cannot get it correctly ,the code i used here:

```
 Document document = new SAXReader().read(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlfile.getBytes("UTF-8")));
 Node foundnode = null;
 Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
 String namespace = rootElement.getNamespaceURI();
 if (namespace != null) {
     DefaultXPath defaultXPath = new DefaultXPath(xpath);
     Map<String, String> namespaces = new TreeMap<String, String>();
     namespaces.put("ns", namespace);
     defaultXPath.setNamespaceURIs(namespaces);
 }
 foundnode = document.selectSingleNode("/ns:s:Envelope/ns:s:Body/ns:CreateResponse/ns:CustomerId");
```

Then it throws below exception :

```
org.dom4j.InvalidXPathException: Invalid XPath expression: /ns:s:Envelope/ns:s:Body/ns:CreateResponse/ns:CustomerId Unexpected ':'
    at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.parse(DefaultXPath.java:360)
    at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.<init>(DefaultXPath.java:59)
    at com.github.becauseQA.xml.DOM4JUtils.getNodes(DOM4JUtils.java:152)
    at
```

I know it caused by the xpath used here ,but i don't know which xpath should i pickup here, you can see the node has : ,so when use the namespace with ns: for each node ,it cannot parse it . Anyone know how to pickup the node with namespace and special character in the node name ? thanks .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
String xml = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><CreateResponse xmlns=\"http://gtestserver/\"><CustomerId>8124138</CustomerId><InternalResponseCode>Success</InternalResponseCode><ResponseCode>0</ResponseCode><ResponseDate>2016-08-31T07:57:22.7760577Z</ResponseDate><ResponseDescription>Success</ResponseDescription><UserId>7424876375</UserId></CreateResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

Document document = new SAXReader().read(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("UTF-8")));
Node foundnode = null;
Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
String namespace = rootElement.getNamespaceURI();

foundnode = document.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='CustomerId']");

System.out.println(foundnode.getText());
```

This returns : `8124138`

Comment: ,Thanks this xpath selector worked for this special case ,thanks very much .